# How to prove the inequality $\frac{x^2 \mid \sin(x^2 y) \mid}{x^4 + y^2} \leq \mid y \mid$

Tags: inequality

I've tried many things, but to no success. I first tried to use the fact that $\mid \sin(x) \mid \leq 1$ to reduce the inequality to $\frac{x^2}{x^4 + y^2} \leq \mid y \mid$, but taking $y = 0$ one gets $\frac{1}{x^2} \leq 0$, which is obviously false. So it seems that the sine is really important and I do not know how to manipulate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to prove such inequality, notice that $|\sin(x^{2}y)|\leq |x^{2}y|$.

Moreover, we do also have that
\begin{align*}
0\leq x^{4} \leq x^{4} + y^{2} \Rightarrow 0\leq \left|\frac{x^{4}}{x^{4} + y^{2}}\right| \leq 1
\end{align*}

Gathering both results, one arrives at
\begin{align*}
0\leq \left|\frac{x^{2}\sin(x^{2}y)}{x^{4} + y^{2}}\right| \leq \left|\frac{x^{4}y}{x^{4} + y^{2}}\right| \leq |y|
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: Oh, it makes so much sense now. Thank you! Now I can solve many other inequalities.

Comment: @LeonardoLovera you are welcome ! I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that

$$\lvert\sin(x)\rvert\leq \lvert x \rvert.$$

This gives you that

\begin{align*}
\frac{x^2\lvert\sin(x^2y)\rvert}{x^4+y^2}&\leq\frac{x^2\lvert x^2y\rvert}{x^4+y^2}\\
&=\frac{x^4}{x^4+y^2}\lvert y\rvert \\
&\leq \lvert y\rvert.
\end{align*}